# Read content using curl

Tags: php, curl

Using Curl i am sending some post data to a server.This is the Header reponse iam getting

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 30 Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/thegateway; Secure P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR" X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Sat, 22 Jan 2011 00:07:25 GMT

how do i read the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option in the curl call?
When it is set, the content of the response is returned by the curl_exec() function itself.

This is a code from a working project of mine:

```
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 

            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => $this->return_content,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers, they are processed through callback
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => $this->follow_redirects,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $this->user_agent, // who am i
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $this->connect_timeout,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $this->request_timeout,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
            );
    $extraheaders = array();            

    $res = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $res, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $res );
```

Comment: I have set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to 1,but still only getting the header content.

Comment: So what does the curl_exec function return? Empty string?

Comment: its returning "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 30 Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/thegateway; Secure P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR" X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Sat, 22 Jan 2011 00:07:25 GMT"